# POST JSON in body request with Jersey

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have a dynamic web project in Java (deployed on a local application server Tomcat 7) which uses Jersey for creating REST APIs.

I do not use any build automation tools (so my libraries are added to the build path and the servlet is inserted in the web.xml file).

The libraries that I am using are:

```
asm-3.1.jar
gson-2.2.1.jar
jersey-client-1.0.3.jar
jersey-core-1.0.3.jar
jersey-json-1.18.jar
jersey-server-1.0.3.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jsr311-api-1.0.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
```

My web.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>UserAccount</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The application is interacting with a MySQL database.
The scenario is the following: The database contains a user account table called users. The columns are id, name, username and password.

I have a POST method for verifying if an account (username + password) are valid. (username and password passed as header params)
http://localhost:8080/UserAccount/rest/login/doLogin
and the headers:
username: x
password: 1234

```
@POST
@Path("/doLogin")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public String doLogin(@HeaderParam("username") String uname, @HeaderParam("password") String pwd){
    String response = "";
    if(checkCredentials(uname, pwd)){
        response = Utility.constructJSON("login",true);
    }else{
        response = Utility.constructJSON("login", false, "Incorrect Email or Password");
    }
return response;        
}
```

As you can see, the response will produce a JSON with true or false, based if the user account is valid or not.
And up to now it works fine. It works fine also doing a GET and passing the params as query params (but that it's not the point).

Now I am trying to do a POST but this time passing the username and password in a JSON body:

```
{
    "username":"x",
    "password":"1234"
}
```

For this I have created a class called User.java:

```
@XmlRootElement()
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name="username")
    private String username;

    @XmlElement(name="password")
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "username: " + username;
    }
}
```

And I have created a method:

```
    //pass the arguments as JSON body
@POST
// Path: http://localhost:8080/UserAccount/rest/login/asklogin
@Path("/askLogin")
// Produces JSON as response
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response askLogin(User user) {
    System.out.println("Inside POST askLogin");
    if(checkCredentials(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword())) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    } else {
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

I am testing the API by using Advanced Rest Client from Google Chrome and REST Easy from Firefox.

I have also created a class which implements the MessageBodyReader as follows:

```
@Provider
public class UserBeanMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<User> {

    //used for MessageBodyReader
    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
            MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == User.class;
    }

    @Override
    public User readFrom(Class<User> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
            MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
            InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
            User user = (User) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(entityStream);
            return user;
        } catch (JAXBException jaxbException) {
            jaxbException.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error deserializing a User" + jaxbException);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

After debugging, the issue is coming here:

```
User user = (User) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(entityStream);
```

and it goes on the catch statement.

The stacktrace is the following:

```
    INFO: Server startup in 1239 ms
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is 

    not allowed in prolog.]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204)
        at ro.useraccount.jersey.UserBeanMessageBodyReader.readFrom(UserBeanMessageBodyReader.java:36)
        at ro.useraccount.jersey.UserBeanMessageBodyReader.readFrom(UserBeanMessageBodyReader.java:1)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:393)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:43)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:126)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:173)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:163)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:612)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:603)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:309)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:425)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:590)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:999)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
        ... 35 more
    Error deserializing a Userjavax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
     - with linked exception:
    [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
    Inside POST askLogin
    Oct 06, 2016 8:57:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ro.useraccount.jersey.Login.askLogin(Login.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:175)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:163)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:111)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:63)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:654)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:612)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:603)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:309)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:425)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:590)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What do you think?

Comment: I'm afraid jersey doesnt support gson or jettison out of box. You can change to use jackson or write your own message body reader and writer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should tell Jersey to use Gson for JSON handling. You can do this implementing the `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` interfaces provided by Jersey. 
In this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516224/using-gson-instead-of-jackson-in-jersey) you can find an example (see the accepted answer).
If you want to add some context to it, take a look at
[the JSON section of the Jersey 1.x manual](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/json.html)

EDIT : 
I may not be understanding your code, but where is the call to Gson in your
`UserBeanMessageBodyReader`?
Try chaging the `reaedFrom` method with something along the lines of

```
String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entityStream))
                 .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
Gson gson = new GSon();
User myUser = gson.fromJson(result, User.class);
```

instead of using `JAXBContext` (which afaict understands only XML inputs).

Comment: Hi Francesco. Today morning I tried with MessageBodyReader (created a separated class with the @Provider annotation). Now it is able to get inside the method askLogin() and it is printing the string on the first line "Inside POST askLogin" but it is still unable to unmarshall. I get this error: Error deserializing a javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]

Comment: I think this has to do with the input you are providing. You should debug the `MessageBodyReader` in order to discover what is causing the exception. Otherwise you could try to change temporarily the `askLogin` service to `@Consumes("text/plain")` and accept `String user` instead of `User user`. This way you should be able to see what Jersey is receiving as input, and hopefully why Gson doesn't like it.

Comment: Just to be sure, try also adding setter methods to `User`. Maybe the problem is just that Gson can't find the setters for the fields in `User`.

Comment: Hi I have tried the solution proposed by you but still doesn't work. I have updated my question including the class which implements the MessageBodyReader interface. I have also added setter to the User class. After debugging it stops after this line: User user = (User) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(entityStream);